# null reference with and if statement c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just want to check for empty text boxes and change the text the boxes if they are null in RowEditing event. I just can't figure this out. Of course the some of the boxes will be empty when the Grid is populated. The other question is am I placing this in the right event?

Here is the row editing event :

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{        
    fill_grid();

    //Set the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    check_grid_boxes();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Here is the check_grid_boxes Method :

```
protected void check_grid_boxes()
{
    if (gtxtLane.Text == "")
    {
        gtxtLane.Text = "0";
    }
    else if (gtxtCarriers.Text == "")
    {
        gtxtCarriers.Text = "0";
    }
    else if (gtxtREV.Text == "")
    { 
        gtxtREV.Text = "0";
    }
    return;
}
```

Before you mention Java Script or Jquery. This is a web control and my attempts at using java has not worked.

I changed my code to this :

```
  protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            fill_grid();
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            var lane = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gtxtLane");
            var car = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gtxtCarriers");
            var badcar = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gtxtBadCarriers");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lane.Text))
            {
                lane.Text = "0";
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(badcar.Text))
            {
                badcar.Text = "0";
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(car.Text))
            {
                car.Text = "0";
            }
               GridView1.DataBind();
         }
```

Comment: What line is raising the exception?

Comment: I know this will sound pedantic, but I think you mean JavaScript not Java. Similar names, two vastly different things.

Comment: The check_grid_boxes method is throwing the exception. I was thinking the way I close the If statements is is wrong with just using return?

Comment: Is `.Text` null or are things like `gtxtLane` null? If it's the first, you're looking for `String.IsNullOrEmpty(gtxtLane.Text)`... (presuming that the empty fields might not be empty strings, but are actually null values...)

Comment: Looks like those input elements are in a row in a GridView, correct?  If so, you can't access them via their ID like you are trying, since _each_ row has those elements.

Comment: You don't need to `return` anything in a `void` method.

Comment: But in that case, `gtxtLane` shouldn't be predeclared. @briskovich, did you add fields for `gtxtLane` and others yourself?

Comment: There is a difference between an `Empty` string and a `Null` string. Your code is only checking to see if the string is empty. Your question and the problem you are trying to solve is not clear.  It sounds like you need to debug this problem a great deal more.

Comment: @hvd - these are item template fields in a gridview that I programmed by hand. I think the problem is calling them by name as Gromer suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DUH!!!! how bout --> select isnull(lane,'0') as Lane <---. I can't believe I didn't think of that!! 6 hours wasted!!

Answer (score 1):

You must get a reference to the TextBoxes that are inside that row being edited like this:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

TextBox gtxtLane = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gtxtLane");
```

Comment: I still get the null reference error. Object not referenced to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do this: `if(lane != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(lane.Text))`. Your problem is that it's not finding the control in the grid row. See if the name of the textbox inside the grid is correct...

Comment: Did you try what Max answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12959735/114029? Add this to your HTML markup in each textbox: `nulldisplaytext="0"`

Comment: Yep I tried that but it did not work. This was a real head scratcher. So I just decided to change my select query and the problem was solved. I also tried the find control method with and if statement but the statement but that would not work either. So the isnull was the way to go and everything is working and off my desk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nulldisplaytext property of the gridview

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="discounttype"
            nulldisplaytext="0"
            headertext="Discount Type"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're getting a reference problem, because the compiler doesn't know where to get `gtxtLane` and the rest from. Remember that each row in the grid has its own version of these controls, so you will need to reference them directly. You can use `FindControl` on the row object. You can get a reference for the row object from `GridViewEditEventArgs`. Your code will look something like this (`e` refers to `GridViewEditEventArgs`)

```
var gtxtLane = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("gtxtLane");
if (gtxtLane.Text == "")
{
    gtxtLane.Text = "0";
}
```

`e.NewEditIndex` gets you the index of the row being edited, we use that to get the row object from the gridview, then we find the wanted control, and cast it to `TextBox`, then use it. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I thought about this very thing but was trying this. I didn't think about how the controls are rendered by the compliler. This makes a lot of sense. I was having the same problem with the update statement and had to use FindControl to add the boxes as parameters.

Comment: @briskovich - You'll run into this sort of thing with all repeater style controls. So it's a good trick to know.

Comment: I made the changes but still get the null reference. Check the edit.

Comment: @briskovich - Which part is giving you the null reference? gtxtLane?

Comment: @briskovich - Yeah I saw that, but I still don't know which statement threw the exception.